# cmake, add_custom_command with dependencies from a different directory

Tags: cmake

I have a question about CMake which seems to be commonly asked here, but none of the answers seem to solve my problem.

In the `details` subdirectory, there is a `CMakeLists.txt` which contains:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT part.out
                   COMMAND foo --input=part.src --output=part.out
                   DEPENDS part.src)

add_custom_target(part_out
                  DEPENDS part.out)
```

In the main directory there is a `CMakeLists.txt` which uses `part.out` for generating another file:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT full.out
                   COMMAND bar --input=./details/part.out --output=full.out)

add_custom_target(full_out
                  DEPENDS full.out)
```

The problem is that I want 3 things to happen here:

1. if `part.out` doesn't exist it needs to be generated
2. if `part.out` is out of date (`part.src` is newer than `part.out`) I want it to be regenerated
3. if `full.out` is out of date (`part.out` is newer than `full.out`, or `full.out` desn't exist) I want it to be (re)generated

So if I add `DEPENDS ./details/part.out` to `add_custom_command(OUTPUT full.out)` I will achieve points 2 and 3, but not point 1, because if I delete `part.out` and then I call `make full_out` I'll get an error that there is no rule to make `./details/part.out` (as it is a rule from another directory).

If I add `DEPENDS full_out` to `add_custom_command(OUTPUT full.out)` or to `add_custom_target(full_out)` I'll achieve points 1 and 2, but not 3, because even if `part.out` was regenerated, a `full.out` will not be regenerated, as it doesn't depend on the `part.out` file itself.

So how can I connect both scenarios?
I was thinking about adding both `DEPENDS` but how do I know if that will always work? I mean in such case the order of build will matter here.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[CMake docs for `add_custom_target`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:add_custom_target):

> By default nothing depends on the custom target. Use ADD_DEPENDENCIES
>   to add dependencies to or from other targets.

So I suggest to "connect" the targets with

```
ADD_DEPENDENCIES( full_out part_out )
```

EDIT:
**Working example**

As it turned out, you need to set the source file properties for `part.out`

Here is my working example (tried under Windows with VS2008):

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 )
project( full )

add_subdirectory( details )

add_custom_command( OUTPUT full.out 
               COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ./details/part.out full.out
               DEPENDS details/part.out 
               )


add_custom_target( full_out
               DEPENDS full.out details/part.out details/part.src
              )


set_source_files_properties( details/part.out PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE ) 


add_dependencies( full_out part_out )
```

details/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 )
project(part)

add_custom_command(OUTPUT part.out
               COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/part.src part.out
               DEPENDS part.src)

add_custom_target(part_out
              DEPENDS part.out)
```

This example worked for all of your 3 stated cases.

Comment: ok, I know how to connect targets. Problem is how to make a custom_command's output get rebuild when a file (which is a result of another custom command **from another directory**) changes

Comment: @MichałWalenciak Hm, I see. See my extended answer for a solution.

Comment: I had to add the ALL flag to the add_custom_target command to get this to work.